# Using Pandas to Extract config file (Looks like K/V but not)

Tags: python, pandas, config

I have a config file in the format below:

```
Models{
    Model1{
        Description = "xxxx"
        Feature = "yyyy"
        EventType = [
            "Type1", 
            "Type2"]
    }

    Model2{
        Description = "aaaa"
        Feature = "bbbb"
        EventType = [
            "Type3", 
            "Type4"]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to transform this into a dataframe as below?

```
|Model  | Description | Feature | EventType    | 
------------------------------------------------
|Model1 | xxxx        | yyyy    | Type1, Type2 |
|Model2 | aaaa        | bbbb    | Type3, Type4 |
```

Comment: Is the data you've provided is from .ini file?

Comment: I think you may have to use some regex to turn this string into something that looks like a json and then use `json.load(string)` which can then be converted using `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` or `pandas.read_json`

Comment: The data extension is in .config. But the format does not look like the common config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should convert it into standard JSON format. You can accomplish that using regex:

```
with open('untitled.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

import re
# Converting into JSON format
data = re.sub(r'(=\s*".*")\n', r'\1,\n', data)
data = re.sub(r'(Description|Feature|EventType)', r'"\1"', data)
data = re.sub(r'}(\s*Model[0-9]+)', r'},\1', data)
data = re.sub(r'(Model[0-9]+)', r'"\1"=', data)
data = re.sub(r'(Models)', r'', data)
data = re.sub(r'=', r':', data)
```

Your file will look like this:

```
{
    "Model1":{
        "Description" : "xxxx",
        "Feature" : "yyyy",
        "EventType" : [
            "Type1", 
            "Type2"]
    },

    "Model2":{
        "Description" : "aaaa",
        "Feature" : "bbbb",
        "EventType" : [
            "Type3", 
            "Type4"]
    }
}
```

Then, use `pd.read_json` to read it:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_json(StringIO(data), orient='index').reset_index()
#        index Description       EventType Feature
#0  Model1        xxxx  [Type1, Type2]    yyyy
#1  Model2        aaaa  [Type3, Type4]    bbbb
```

Comment: Hi ibarrond, I noticed that the regex is looking for variations of Model#. Is there a way to find the "Model" if there were not so consistent? Example, Model-abc, Model-defg", etc.

Comment: Of course there is! Instead of posting you a single answer, I encourage you to try https://regex101.com/ and create your own regex applied to your data

Comment: Noted. Thanks for lead.